# Visual Studio 2015 get IPendingChangesExt

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I tried to get the service IPendingChangesExt in my Visual Studio 2015 extension, to access the Related Work Items in the Team Explorer - Pending Changes window. But it alway return null.

I tried it with this line of code in my Package class:

```
 object temp = this.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.Extensibility.IPendingChangesExt));
```

Did anyone have an idea, why it returns null? Was it replaced with an other interface or somethng else?

Another question: Exists a list with all available services in Visual Studio 2015?

Best Regards,
Muck

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using TFS2015 in your environment?

Comment: At the moment we using TFS2013. But we want change at the beginning of 2017.

Answer (score 0):

We can only get IPendingChangesExt instance in visual studio 2013, we can get IPendingChangesExt instance via Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer, like this:

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer teamExplorer;

```
teamExplorer = base.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer))
                   as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer;


  var teamExplorerPage = teamExplorer.NavigateToPage(new Guid(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.TeamExplorerPageIds.PendingChanges), null);

  var pendingChangesExt = teamExplorerPage.GetExtensibilityService(
                   typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.Extensibility.IPendingChangesExt))
                   as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.Extensibility.IPendingChangesExt;
```